# Webservicex.net allowed use of services

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I have been playing around with the currency converter web service offered by http://webservicex.net as a way of learning how to interact with a web service from an iPhone application and I have managed to get the currency converter working perfectly.

I have since expanded my application to include other features to make it something a little 'different' from what is currently available on the App Store.

The question that I have is if I release an app on the App Store and that is ad-supported am I allowed to use this web service that someone has obviously put time and effort into making? Up until a month ago I did not even know what a web service was or how it existed so I am not sure if there is any etiquette (eg, give them a mention in the About page of your app) or if these things are generally out there and free to use?

I have tried contacting Webservice X via email but every time I get a bouceback because their mailbox is full, which has helped get me closer to an answer. Has anyone else used their services or know of the standard allowed use of someone elses web service in an ad-supported application?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using their web-service is not going to get you rejected.  That being said, relying on someone else's equipment (of which you have no control and are not paying for usage) is not a good idea for a production app.  I would do some research into finding a service that you feel is going to be more reliable or can pay (a minimal amount) to use.

The other piece of advice I would give is to build the application so that it gets the data from your own web-service and let all the base data come from you.  In other words, get your own web-site (from as little as $7 a month from GoDaddy or other services), and do the currency lookups there.  Build your server-side processes to be easy to swap from one service to another and that way if for some reason you lose access to the currency converter service you have been using, it is a quick amount of work to switch to a different one without having to release a whole new version of the application (and wait 7+ days for the app review process).

In other words, your web-service you build supplies all the data for the iOS app and you get the currency data on your web-server.

That is how I would do it to make sure it is the most reliable and easiest to change without affecting the installed iOS app.